# What do I do with my dead fish?

Tags: aquarium, fish, death

I came home earlier to find that my fish had died. I wasn't expecting this to happen as he was supposed to live for a really long time. So this is a situation that wasn't thought about much. I do not want to bury him, flush him down the toilet, cremate him or give him to animals to eat. Are there any other options? At the moment he is still floating in my tank so please help.
Is there even a way of keeping him in a hygienic way?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry you lost your fishy.

He is still with you in your memories of him… You do not need to keep his body.

However since you asked about hygienic options you could have him cremated and keep his ashes. Another option (which is rather gruesome to me at least) would be to seal him in a jar with formaldehyde.

I would still advise it would be best for you, him and everyone to return him to the earth or water somehow so his death can perpetuate other life.